# apiserver not coming up after adding audit-policy-file param

Tags: kubernetes, audit

[Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/)

I want to add audit-policy-file param and file is present in /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml

It has basic metadata logging rule.

But once i restart service apiserver is not coming up. If i keep value empty then it works fine and log in /var/log/containers say file read failed.

> {"log":"\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-12-24T12:23:36.82013719Z"}
>   {"log":"error: loading audit policy file: failed to read file path \"/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml\": open /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml: no such file or directory\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-12-24T12:23:36.820146912Z"}

```
[root@kube2-master containers]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:39:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:31:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
[root@kube2-master containers]# cat /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
rules:
- level: Metadata
```

```
[root@kube2-master containers]# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --advertise-address=192.168.213.23
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.213.23
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
status: {}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're running the `kube-apiserver` as a pod, so it's looking for that audit file on the filesystem *inside* the container, whereas you're putting it on the filesystem of the host. You need to mount that path through to your `kube-apiserver` pod. Assuming you're using `kubeadm`, add the following to your `ClusterConfiguration`:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiServer:
  extraVolumes:
    - name: audit-policy
      hostPath: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      readOnly: true
```

Comment: Yeap that worked for me thanks.. I kept this file in already mounting folder and added it's location appropriately